# Detect Apple Watch is paired or registered in this iPhone in my app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-watch

I need to find if my phone is paired with a any apple watch and get some information about the paired watch like its name. I tried reading the documentation but I couldn't seem to find any thing specific to my use case.

Reason why I need to use this :
Firstly, Taking data from phone I can know if's user uses apple watch or not. If they used apple watch, then I need to give alert to the user when they open my app

If they DON'T used apple watch, then I need to NO alert to the user when they open my app

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may help if you elaborate as to *why* you need this information & what you’ll be using it for.

Comment: I don't believe you can find out unless your app also has a watch app that the user has installed